# MySQL Regex to check if value is not an array of UUID-s

Tags: mysql, regex

I currently use this regex to check if a column's value is not an UUID:

```
'WHERE Answer.value NOT REGEXP "[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}"'
```

But, because I am not very good at using Regex-es, I stumbled upon the issue of detecting an JSON-encoded array, which contains at least one element NOT being an UUID. Any help about this one?

My proposal:

```
"WHERE Answer.value NOT REGEXP '\[(\"[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\"(\,)?)*\]'"
```

but before I test this in a huge system where error detection is difficult, I'd love to have some feedback from you.

It looks [OK at the first glance](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5C%5B(%5C%22%5Ba-fA-F0-9%5D%7B8%7D-%5Ba-fA-F0-9%5D%7B4%7D-%5Ba-fA-F0-9%5D%7B4%7D-%5Ba-fA-F0-9%5D%7B4%7D-%5Ba-fA-F0-9%5D%7B12%7D%5C%22(%5C%2C)%3F)*%5C%5D%2F), but maybe there are some issues which I am not able to see as for now.

It should match for example the following arrays:

```
[], ["UUID1"], ["UUID1", "UUID2"]
```

but not the following ones:

```
["Cat"], ["UUID1", "Dog"], ["[]"]
```

The arrays are *never* nested (always single level).

Comment: "json-encoded array" is pretty meaningless. an array can take pretty much any form, with as many layers of nesting as you want. it'd be pretty much impossible to write a regex to properly detect such a structure, v.s. a meaningless string filled with random `[` and `]` - just like it's impossible to write a regex that can handle 100% of all html.

Comment: I've added some additional info.

Comment: you can just check if there is a nested array or not !